# How do I say “Please do not add too much oil” in Korean?

Tags: spoken-korean, phrase-request, phrases

I plan to visit a Korean restaurant and would like to avoid eating oily foods. Can someone please tell me how to ask the waiter to not add too much oil to the foods?

Comment: where is this Korean restaurant? Depending on the location they probably speak the local language

Comment: https://papago.naver.com/?sk=en&tk=ko&hn=0&st=Please%20do%20not%20add%20too%20much%20oil%E2%80%9D%20in%20Korean%3F

Answer (score 1):

You may politely say

> "기름 많이 넣지 말아 주세요." (Don't add oil much.)

or a bit differently,

> "기름기 많지 않게 해 주세요." (Don't make it oily.)

Nevertheless, *I doubt whether they will respond to your request* especially when oil is one of the main ingredients or when they have to use oily ingredients (chicken, beef, pork, ...). Additionally, some cooking styles (부침개, 튀김, 볶음, ...) require using oil much. It could be better to look up recipes before ordering food or to ask which dishes are not oily. For the latter, you may say

> "어떤 게 기름기가 적나요?" (Which one is less oily?)

or

> "기름기 적은 음식이 뭔가요?" (What dish has (a) little oil?)

when you converse with the waiter.

> **Pronunciation notes**
>
> 1. 많이 is pronounced as 마니.
> 2. 넣지 as 너치.
> 3. 기름기 as 기름끼.
> 4. 말아 as 마라.
> 5. 많지 as 만치.
> 6. 않게 as 안케.
> 7. 적나요 as 정나요.

Answer (score 0):

oily, greasy = 기름진, 느끼한

Do not be greasy

기름지지 않게 해주세요

느끼하지 않게 해주세요

기름기 빼주세요 (Rule out oils).

@ 담백하다 be in a state not flooding in given standards in major
directions.

Do not give flavor = Do not add tastes 맛을 더하지 말아 주세요. 담백하게 해주세요

@ 느끼한 자식 = a man whose activity to girls makes us cringe
오글거리게 만드는 행동을 잘하는 사람.